# In the following example of React ES6, how is it possible for an object property referenced w/o the 'this.state'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I pulled this example from a tutorial I was following. I am perplexed with the situation where the selectedGif property is able to refer to "selectedGif" w/o "this.state" as required by other property references such as "this.state.gifs." Is that rule an exception when an arrow function is applied?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onGifSelect inline event handler is not referencing `selectedGif` from `this.state`.

It is being passed an anonymous function written using **[ES6 arrow function notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**.

So:

`selectedGif => this.openModal(selectedGif)`

is *nearly* equivalent to:

```
function(selectedGif) {
  return this.openModal(selectedGif);
}
// NB: Using the latter to invoke `openModal` will THROW AN ERROR 
// because `onModal` is invoked within the inline event handler 
// '`onGifSelect`' and **not** the component scope/context.  

// The result is that the  `this` within `onModal` refers to the
// inline event and not the component context `this` where `setState` exists.
```

There are a couple of ways to get around the above issue:

- using [**`.bind()`**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es6-classes)

OR

- Using the arrow function (`=>`) syntax remedies this because:
  **arrow functions do not create their own scope/context** 
  so invoking `this.setState` within `openModal` will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I hope you found it helpful

Comment: actually I'm wondering, why does some functions pass-ins for prop have nested function and the outer function as the arrow function? Wouldn't it be much simpler to just pass in what's already inside the inner function? So set onGifSelect = {this.openModel(selectGif)}, not the way the tutorial writes.

Comment: Nvm, I got tripped up on that for a bit. But, it has to do with the fact that the regular function would create its own "this," which doesn't point to the class object, so using arrow function which doesn't create its own "this" as you mentioned is resolves that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not referencing `this.state.selectedGif`. It kind of looks like it, but it's just referencing a variable in an anonymous function that could have gone by any other name. The above code would behave precisely the same written like

```
onGifSelect={foo => this.openModal(foo)}
```

aka

```
onGifSelect={(function(foo) { this.openModal(foo) }).bind(this)}
```

But this function isn't making any use of its argument rather than pass it along. It would be better written as

```
onGifSelect={this.openModal}
```

without the extra wrapping function that only serves to retain the surrounding context. Would be better to bind the function in the constructor or use class arrow notation if you have stage-2 enabled https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields

Comment: The extra wrapping ensures the correct context for the method. You'd at least need to pass `this.openModal.bind(this)`.

Comment: @Bergi Stage 1 class arrows are nicer for that, or binding in the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's a nicer solution, but you can't claim that the "*extra wrapping function does nothing*".

Comment: fair enough, I just meant it's not adding anything useful. you're right though, the arrow retains context. updated answer